# Add rules and extract text from PDF using C# .net

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, text-extraction

I want to build a PDF text extraction tool having similar features to this application (A-PDF Data Extractor) http://www.a-pdf.com/data-extractor/index.htm

I am planning to do this in c# .net so I want to build my own interface similar to this app buy referencing this application(dll or exe). But it wont let me to add reference.

How can I do this ? Is there a way to run another application inside my c# desktop application ?

If you have a better options please let me know

```
  Thank You
```

Any help is appreciate!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the exe file you must use the Process Class in the .net Framework.
You have some example here: http://dotnetperls.com/process-start

If you need a library to extract the text from the pdf try to use iTextSharp: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/PDFToText.aspx

Hope this helps